# Vertex Labels in igraph R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am using igraph to plot a non directed force network.

I have a dataframe of `nodes` and `links` as follows:

```
> links
  source target  value sourceID targetID
1      3      4 0.6245  1450552  1519842
2      6      8 0.5723  2607133  3051992
3      9      7 0.7150  3101536  3025831
4      0      1 0.7695   401517   425784
5      2      5 0.5535  1045501  2258363

> nodes
      name group size
1   401517     1    8
2   425784     1    8
3  1045501     1    8
4  1450552     1    8
5  1519842     1    8
6  2258363     1    8
7  2607133     1    8
8  3025831     1    8
9  3051992     1    8
10 3101536     1    8
```

I plot these using `igraph` as follows:

```
gg <- graph.data.frame(links,directed=FALSE)
plot(gg, vertex.color = 'lightblue', edge.label=links$value, vertex.size=1, edge.color="darkgreen", 
     vertex.label.font=1, edge.label.font =1, edge.label.cex = 1, 
     vertex.label.cex = 2 )
```

[image]

On this plot, igraph has used the proxy indexes for `source` and `target` as vertex labels.

I want to use the real ID's, in my `links` table expressed as `sourceID` and `targetID`.

So, for:

```
  source target  value sourceID targetID
1      3      4 0.6245  1450552  1519842
```

This would show as:

```
(1450552) ----- 0.6245 ----- (1519842)
```

Instead of:

```
      (3) ----- 0.6245 ----- (4)
```

(Note that the proxy indexes are zero indexed in the `links` dataframe, and one indexed in the `nodes` dataframe. This offset by 1 is necessary for `igraph` plotting).

I know I need to somehow `match` or `map` the proxy indexes to their corresponding `name` within the `nodes` dataframe. However, I am at a loss as I do no not know the order in which igraph plots labels.

How can I achieve this?

I have consulted the following questions to no avail:

[Vertex Labels in igraph with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335944/vertex-labels-in-igraph-with-r)
[how to specify the labels of vertices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352227/how-to-specify-the-labels-of-vertices-in-r)
[R igraph rename vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433402/r-igraph-rename-vertices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the labels like this:

```
 library(igraph)
gg <- graph.data.frame(
  links,directed=FALSE, 
  vertices = rbind(
    setNames(links[,c(1,4)],c("id","label")), 
    setNames(links[,c(2,5)], c("id","label"))))
plot(gg, vertex.color = 'lightblue', edge.label=links$value, 
     vertex.size=1, edge.color="darkgreen", 
     vertex.label.font=1, edge.label.font =1, edge.label.cex = 1, 
     vertex.label.cex = 2 )
```

[image]

You could also pass

```
merge(rbind(
    setNames(links[,c(1,4)],c("id","label")), 
    setNames(links[,c(2,5)], c("id","label"))), 
    nodes, 
    by.x="label", by.y="name")
```

to the vertices argument if you needed the other node attributes.

Data:

```
 links <- read.table(header=T, text="
  source target  value sourceID targetID
1      3      4 0.6245  1450552  1519842
2      6      8 0.5723  2607133  3051992
3      9      7 0.7150  3101536  3025831
4      0      1 0.7695   401517   425784
5      2      5 0.5535  1045501  2258363")

 nodes <- read.table(header=T, text="
      name group size
1   401517     1    8
2   425784     1    8
3  1045501     1    8
4  1450552     1    8
5  1519842     1    8
6  2258363     1    8
7  2607133     1    8
8  3025831     1    8
9  3051992     1    8
10 3101536     1    8")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really useful. When you say `you could pass ... to the vertices argument` what exactly do you mean? Do you mean to set `vertex.attr = merge....`?

Comment: I meant `graph.data.frame(..., vertices = merge(...))`.

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as, even though I used a different method, I believe yours has the wider use case and provides more informatory benefit. Thanks again, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears I was able to repurpose the answer to this question to achieve this.

[r igraph - how to add labels to vertices based on vertex id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909240/r-igraph-how-to-add-labels-to-vertices-based-on-vertex-id)

The key was to use the `vertex.label` attribute within `plot()` and a select a sliced subset of `nodes$names`.

For our index we can use the ordered default labels returned in `igraph` automatically. To extract these, you can type `V(gg)$names`.

Within `plot(gg)` we can then write:

```
vertex.label = nodes[c(as.numeric(V(gg)$name)+1),]$name
# 1 Convert to numeric
# 2 Add 1 for offset between proxy links index and nodes index
# 3 Select subset of nodes with above as row index. Return name column
```

As full code:

```
gg <- graph.data.frame(links,directed=FALSE)
plot(gg, vertex.color = 'lightblue', edge.label=links$value, vertex.size=1, edge.color="darkgreen", 
     vertex.label.font=1, edge.label.font =1, edge.label.cex = 1, 
     vertex.label.cex = 2, vertex.label = nodes[c(as.numeric(V(gg)$name)+1),]$name)
```

With the data above, this gave:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to reorder the columns of `links`, because according to the documentation:

> "If vertices is NULL, then the first two columns of d are used as a symbolic edge list and additional columns as edge attributes."

Hence, your code will give the correct output after running:

```
links <- links[,c(4,5,3)]
```